# Wordpress custom loop

Tags: wordpress, foreach, while-loop

need help to make loop like this:
http://prntscr.com/eswtyt

With 2 arrow styles (left and right).

1) item with left arrow 2) item with left arrow
3) item with right arrow 4) item with right arrow
5) item with left arrow 6) item with left arrow
etc...

My loop now:

```
<?php 
                    $services = get_posts(array(
                        'meta_query' => array(
                            array(
                                'key' => 'enable_service_in_homepage',
                                'compare' => '==',
                                'value' => '1'
                            )
                        )
                    ));

                    if( $services ): 
                ?>
                <?php foreach( $services as $post ):  setup_postdata( $post ) ?>
                    <div class="col-sm-6 nopadding">
                        <div class="item item-left">
                            <div class="col-sm-6 nopadding hidden-xs">
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail( array(700, 500) ); ?></a>
                                <div class="arrow-left"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6 nopadding">
                                <div class="content">
                                    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                                    <p><?php echo wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), 35, '...' ); ?></p>
                                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="service-button"><?php echo __('ƏTRAFLI','altus'); ?></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Start right arrow -->
                        <div class="col-sm-6 nopadding">
                            <div class="item item-right">
                                <div class="col-md-6 nopadding">
                                    <div class="content">
                                        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                                        <p><?php echo wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), 35, '...' ); ?></p>
                                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="service-button"><?php echo __('ƏTRAFLI','altus'); ?></a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-6 nopadding hidden-xs">
                                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail( array(700, 500) ); ?></a>
                                    <div class="arrow-right"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <!-- End right arrow -->
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: So, what's the question?

Comment: sorry for my bad english.
im need help make layout like in picture, in my loop now have only left arrow, have comment <!-- Start right arrow --> where start another layout with right arrow. need grid like this:

1) item with left arrow 2) item with left arrow 
3) item with right arrow 4) item with right arrow 
5) item with left arrow 6) item with left arrow

Comment: I would suggest that you omit the second half of the code (start right arrow comment and beyond) and remove the "arrow-left" class from the top portion of your code and replace it with code that alternates between printing "arrow-left" and "arrow-right". Are you looking for help figuring out how to alternate?

Comment: Add little example please, i think need second layout like my block with comment, every 2nd row image in right and content in left

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be a more clean way of doing this, but you can accomplish it with [array_chunk()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php):

```
<?php
$services = get_posts(array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'enable_service_in_homepage',
            'compare' => '==',
            'value' => '1'
        )
    )
));
?>
<?php if( $services ): ?>
    <?php $services_chunked = array_chunk( $services, 2 ); ?>
    <?php foreach( $services_chunked as $key => $posts ): ?>
        <?php $alignment = $key % 2 ? "left" : "right"; ?>
        <?php foreach ( $posts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
            <div class="col-sm-6 nopadding">
                <div class="item item-<?= $alignment ?>">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 nopadding hidden-xs">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail( array(700, 500) ); ?></a>
                        <div class="arrow-<?= $alignment ?>"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 nopadding">
                        <div class="content">
                            <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                            <p><?php echo wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), 35, '...' ); ?></p>
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="service-button">Altus</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```